# Android kernel debug

Tags: android, debugging, kernel

I would debug the kernel (via gdb) of my Android device (Samsung S5).
I can extract the kernel image? If yes I can dubug it (like `$arm-eabi-gdb vmlinux` and `$target remote localhost:4444`)?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Thanks